# How to remove matching lines excluding certain others?

Tags: regex, perl

If I have the following in a variable

```
\item () $0.25$
  \item () $0.7$
\item 
  \item
```

how do I then remove the lines that matche `\item` but not those that have a set of `()`?

If I do

```
$f =~ s|\\item.*?(?!\()||g;
```

then it deletes all `\item` for some reason.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are searching if there's a position after `\item` that's not followed by `(`. There is in all cases.

```
\item () $0.25$
     ^ ^^^^^^^^^  These positions aren't followed by "("
```

The `.*?` should be in the `(?!)`.

```
s{ ^ .*? \\item (?! [^(\n]* \( ) .* \n }{}mgx
```